# CSS not getting applied in some browsers

Tags: css

I have a search bar plugin (Wordpress) which I have modified by CSS to suit my design. The thing is that it gets displayed ok in my latest version of Chrome, but it doesn't in other versions of it or Internet Explorer.

Here is how it should be everywhere: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fO1W.png

Here is how it is displayed in iExplorer and some other cases: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKNoW.png

The URL is: [impresionados.net](http://impresionados.net)

The CSS: http://pastebin.com/bjpLS3DM

After having a look it seems like the custom styles are being applied in the first situation, but not on the second one. I have looked for missing semi-colons or closing curly braces, but I haven't seen anyone missmatching.

Where could the problem be or which tools could help me identify the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have a look at the actual CSS?

Comment: Edit the css styles in the Theme's Style file  not directly in the plugin's CSS style file.

Comment: Post your css code pls

Comment: Which version of ie causes the problem?

Comment: @Severin, I have added the custom CSS

Comment: @Joy_S I have, although I don't think it would make it apply in some cases and not on others if everything is well defined.

Comment: Ok. You wrapped almost all your code in media-queries, that can only be interpreted by some browsers. You might want to think about implementing http://modernizr.com/ to create fallbacks for that scenario.

Comment: @Igle Done, although it is a bit messy right now... :S.

Comment: @AlexanderMyshov I'm with iExplorer 11 under Win7, but it also happens with Chrome in some other setups. Weird.
Thank you all!

Comment: @Severin Thanks a lot. I would think iExplorer 11 and not so old versions of Chrome would interpret those correctly though, am I mistaken? Great tip anyway for the older cases!

Comment: @JacoboPolavieja Post your code here instead of pastebin in case it's deleted there and would be inconsistant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrapped almost all your code in media-queries, that can only be interpreted by some browsers. You might want to think about implementing http://modernizr.com/ to create fallbacks for that scenario.

Have a look at http://caniuse.com/#search=media to check to what extend you can use certain CSS selectors.

Comment: So... curiously enough, on the site you mention, it states support for media queries by iExplorer since 9.0. But after removing the media queries code from my CSS it effectively works ok. So I don't quite get why it isn't working as it was with Internet Explorer 11, but at least I've found the source of the problem. Thank you so much for the help!